# Same recipe but sometimes white chocolate cookies come out strange

Tags: baking, freezing, chocolate, cookies

I always use the same recipe (weight everything including eggs) but occasionally the white chocolate cookies come out funny.

When baking in the oven I can see them making bubbles constantly, they always come out flatter and taste doughy.

Here is a video showing the bubbles while in the oven: http://youtu.be/ZLA1h3HzkXY

What could be happening here?

Note: I melt the butter, use a bit of baking soda and bake them from frozen. But it only happens with white chocolate, that's what is strange!

From the same dough batch that was divided into two:

[image: cookies]

Comment: I find it hard to imagine that the chocolate chips color has something to do with it. Maybe there is another factor? When you make both, do you always bake the dark ones first and the white ones second? Or maybe the other way round? If your white-chips dough is warmer before going in because it stood on the counter after shaping, or if the oven is not yet hot enough for the early batches, or overheated for the late ones, this could explain it.

Comment: Are you using the same brands of white and milk chocolate chips?  Perhaps there's a difference in their moisture content that's throwing things off.

Comment: hey everybody. some answers:
yes i use the same brand (very good brand)

Comment: hey everybody. some answers:
-yes i use the same chocolate brand (very good brand) @logophobe

what you watched the video? its so strange those bubbles coming out of the white choc cookies, isnt it? its like plenty of air escaping from the cookies :/

i run a small cookie shop. i got the best recipe ever. my cookies are yummy but rarely the white choc ones turn out like this. i dont get it!

Comment: -i bake them at the same time @rumtscho

Comment: @user25106 The video actually reinforces my answer below.  The bubbling appears to be at the bottom of the cookies.  It looks to me a lot like the sizzle that you get when sauteeing in a pan.  I think it's excess fat "melting" out of the cookies, causing the browning we see at the edges and the slightly flatter shape.

Comment: i made the same recipe two days ago (same ingredients same place same temperature same freezer and baked the white chocolate cookies one today and they came out perfect! this is what i dont understand! sometimes its perfect and sometimes they all form bubbles, come out strange and taste kinda bad. @logophobe

Comment: @user25106 They taste bad as well?  How old is this batch of dough?  How old was it when you put it into the freezer?

Comment: no the last ones i made didnt form bubbles and tasted perfect! (as usual actually) i prepare the dough then refridgirate it for 24 hours and then freeze it up overnight before baking them. always the same recipe always the same way and same temperature! @logophobe

Comment: from the batch that was bad i took off the white chocolate chips and baked a plain cookie and it did form bubbles while baking, got a strange shape and colour as well! so i guess there is a chemical reaction happening to the dough when in contact with the white chocolate chips when sitting in the fridge and then freezer. the question remains: why does this happen on some occasions only and not all the time? @logophobe

Answer (score 5):

White chocolate [has a higher fat content than milk chocolate](http://www.davidlebovitz.com/2006/02/white-chocolate/).  That's very likely throwing off the balance in your dough.  Even though you're using the same batch, more fat is being added to the white chocolate cookies as the chips break down.

You may need to reduce the butter or margarine that you use for the white chocolate cookie dough by a bit.  It's probably a very fine difference, perhaps 10-25% less butter.  That's a bit of a guess but please let us know your results if you give this a try.